# 2FA Identity Management Authentication

Tags: security, authentication

My company is planning to introduce an user login with higher security requirements for the Service Tools in our machines (used for the maintenance). Up to now we used to login with a simple PW which is gradually known by everyone.

The new authentication method should require a 2FA. Every service technican is equipped with a smart phone so I thought of the following authentication process:

The phone number of the service technicans will be registered on a server (independent of the machine) and they will be able to request the code only via this phone maybe in combination with the serial number of the machine. The code will be sent automatically on the requester’s smart phone. With this code the service technican is able to login at the machine and he has access to the service tools.

My problem is: I hear a lot about Identity Management and frameworks as well as public / private key methods. 
The sticking point is that our machines are running offline. So the first requirement is that we are able to manage the service technicans (add / delete permissions for service technicans) on the server (Name, ID, etc.) so they can request a code (2FA) and the second is that they can login at the machine even though the machine is offline.

How can I manage that the Login at the machine is decoupled of the identity managemend on the server side? Is there an easier way to do a login at a offline machine with higher security?

Comment: The only way how I can see it is that the phone would communicate with the server (directly or indirectly) somehow. Can you set up a local network or Bluetooth? I don't see how else the server would ever know that the technician authenticated with his phone.

Comment: Also because the servers are offline I would probably look for some other ways than mobile phones. How about smartcards or any kind of hardware tokens protected by a pin code / passphrase?

Comment: Please let me clarify the situation:
There could be a server (online) which contains the Identitfy Management. And there are the machines, which have to be serviced, which is only possible via a login. The login must therefore determine whether a person is entitled or not.
The smart phone could be a possibility for a 2FA.

Comment: @quinz In principle, I would like to introduce a access management in our machines for our service technicians to do the maintenance. The problem is that the machines are offline - so how can i manage the users and their permissions? Up to now there is just a static password and I would like to increase the security.

Answer (score 0):

**User-Based Authentication**

You will first want to connect your systems with a central identity management Server (LDAP based). With this, every user will have their own account and you will have a system to easily manage them. My recommendation based on your requirements would be the [Univention Corporate Server (UCS)](https://www.univention.com/solutions/solution-scenarios/identity-management-ucs/)

You should easily be able to connect your Service Tools with it using Security Assertion Markup Language (SAML) with the identity management server as identity provider. (Implemented feature, which is detailed in its documentation)
As you unfortunately haven't told us more about your Tools and their possibilities, I can't give you a direct explanation on how to do this.

**Adding a second Factor to the Authentication**

With this done, your users will be able to use their own accounts and passwords. To add a second factor to their authentication, you can use the software [privacyID3A](https://www.privacyidea.org/). It is designed for your needs and is also already implemented as an [App](https://www.univention.com/products/univention-app-center/app-catalog/privacyidea/) in UCS, which should make it even easier to deploy.

Your users can use the [FreeOTP Authenticator](https://freeotp.github.io/), the [Google Authenticator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.authenticator2&hl=en) or other [Supported Tokens](https://privacyidea.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration/supported_tokens.html).

**Needed Connections (Answering your 'offline' note)**

Your machines will need a connection to your identity management server. The ports they communicate on are determined by the services you want to auth your users for. (SSH/Sudo will need PAM, SAML will need HTTPS, and so on)
You won't be able to outsource the authentication from each machine, if they actually are offline and not connected with anything else.
The only machine that has to be partly accessible from the internet will be your identity management server and this only on certain ports to be reachable by your Tokens. The most secure way to do this would be a simple tunnel for these ports.

Answer (score 0):

Many IAM server application will help you there to achieve that but the connection between your applicative Server and the IAM server will be necessary. If zoning is strong in your ecosystem, you can plan for multiples Front-End and having one shared DB backend.

Please note that any IAM solution that brings offline MFA capabilities also brings new risks in the equation as MFA challenge are oftenly pre-computed and stored within a local cache. Local cache that can be hacked.

My best recommendations will be for RCDevs (https://www.rcdevs.com/) as IAM server which needs few change to the way your users authenticate to a server (both Linux or Windows) can add MFA capabilities for very small costs as it support open format for OTP (such as OATH).

From there all communications between applicative server and IAM server are Webservices based (HTTPS) which ease the firewall port opening and Web filtering security controls.

RCDevs provides with a full Soft/hard token enrolment system (including workflows) and innovative way to authenticate (such as QRCode).

Identites can be managed in LDAP dedicated or based on Acitve Directory.

The user is asked to provide then login, password and code along different flows and what you need.

Ask me more if needed as it is a broad subject.

Jeff